# Writing outputs to log file and console

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, logging

In Unix shell, I have a env file (*env file defines the parameters required for running the user script like log file name and path, redirect outputs and errors to log file, database connection details, etc*) which redirects all the outputs (*echo messages*) and errors to the log file from the executed script using the following code:

```
exec 1>>${LOG_FILE}
exec 2>>${LOG_FILE}
```

The env file is executed at the beginning of each script. Due to the above code in env file all the console outputs that might be user outputs or errors are directly output to the log file which is what I actually needed.

But there are some selective user outputs which I want to be displayed in both the console and the log file. But because of the above code I am not able to do so.

I know that if I remove the above code I can get the desired result for this case, but I will have to manually write all other outputs to the log file which is not an easy task.

Is there a way to get the output in both the console and the log file without removing the above codes?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
```

would send stdout and stderr output into the log file, but would also leave you with fd 3 connected to the console, so you can do

```
echo "Some console message" 1>&3
```

to write a message just to the console, or

```
echo "Some console and log file message" | tee /dev/fd/3
```

to write a message to *both* the console *and* the log file - `tee` sends its output to both its own fd 1 (which here is the `LOG_FILE`) and the file you told it to write to (which here is fd 3, i.e. the console).

Example:

```
exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1

echo "This is stdout"
echo "This is stderr" 1>&2
echo "This is the console (fd 3)" 1>&3
echo "This is both the log and the console" | tee /dev/fd/3
```

would print

```
This is the console (fd 3)
This is both the log and the console
```

on the console and put

```
This is stdout
This is stderr
This is both the log and the console
```

into the log file.

Comment: It worked just as you suggested. But I didn't understand **tee /dev/fd/3**. I know that tee writes message to log file and console, but I didn't exactly understand the **/dev/fd/3** used after tee

Comment: @shrestha it's an unusual use of tee, I agree. The `/dev/fd/3` is a file name that refers to "the currently open fd 3", so `tee /dev/fd/3` will write whatever arrives on its stdin to fd 1 and also fd 3 (the `/dev/fd/3` file). Fd 1 is connected to the log file, fd 3 is connected to the console.

Comment: Also you want only want to write to a file and not the console try:
```echo "blah" | tee file1.txt | tee file2.txt >/dev/null```

'Blah' will not be put in file1.txt & file2.txt, but not written to the console.

Comment: This was very helpful for me. Although I noticed something that might be off topic but maybe some of you know the reasons for this. Im executing R scripts from a bash script. The console output of various R functions is colored (as I defined it). when using the above approach to redirect the output to console AND logfile, the console output is not colored anymore. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @dieHellste some programs are able to detect when their output is being piped to another process (in this case `tee`, which in turn writes to the terminal) rather than going directly to a terminal, and adjust their output to match.

Comment: Instead of `1>>${LOG_FILE}`, it is better to write it as `1>>"$LOG_FILE"` to prevent word splitting issues.  We don't need the curly braces anyway.

Comment: When I try `echo "Some console message" && sleep 10 1>&3` it does not write into file till the sleep is completed. Is there any way to write into file right away?

Answer (score 55):

I tried joonty's answer, but I also got the

> exec: 1: not found

error. This is what works best for me ([confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460186/writing-outputs-to-log-file-and-console/22373735?noredirect=1#comment61282198_22373735) to work in zsh also):

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE=/tmp/both.log
exec > >(tee ${LOG_FILE}) 2>&1
echo "this is stdout"
chmmm 77 /makeError
```

The file /tmp/both.log afterwards contains

```
this is stdout
chmmm command not found
```

The /tmp/both.log is appended unless you remove the -a from tee.

Hint: `>(...)` is a process substitution. It lets the `exec` to the `tee` command as if it were a file.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, whereas the other answers have been hit or miss.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this snippet. This seems to be working just fine (compared to the other answers)!

Comment: This works, but now my shell is different after execution.

Comment: @JoshUsre If you want any help or you want to help other SO-users, please explain what is different, and describe your shell, version, OS etc..

Comment: Bash in RHEL 7.  After execution, my term colors are gone and when I launch vi it throws a warning saying I'm not running it from a terminal.  It's possible that I copied it wrong or something but I used it verbatim.  What else can I provide (and please describe how, I'm not a certified admin or anything)?

Comment: This works great for me :)
But I wanted to modify the command so that on each run, the output is appended to an existing log file - how can I do this?
Ok - found it by using `tee -a`

Answer (score 47):

Yes, you want to use `tee`:

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Just pipe your command to tee and pass the file as an argument, like so:

```
exec 1 | tee ${LOG_FILE}
exec 2 | tee ${LOG_FILE}
```

This both prints the output to the STDOUT and writes the same output to a log file. See `man tee` for more information.

Note that this won't write stderr to the log file, so if you want to combine the two streams then use:

```
exec 1 2>&1 | tee ${LOG_FILE}
```

Comment: The above solution did not work. I have redirect.env file as:

#####redirect.env######
export LOG_FILE=log.txt
exec 1 2>&1 | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
exec 1 | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
exec 2 | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
#########

and the working file contained following code:
#####output.sh#####
#!/bin/sh
. redirect.env

echo "Valid output"
ech "invalid output"
##############

but I get the error:
####
redirect.env: line 3: exec: 1: not found
redirect.env: line 5: exec: 1: not found
redirect.env: line 6: exec: 2: not found
####
and in the log file I get the same error as well. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It's very hard to tell, as the new lines are stripped out in your comment. Could you add a paste of the code on somewhere like [gist](http://gist.github.com)?

Comment: I have added the files to the link [UnixRedirect](https://github.com/sthabinash/UnixRedirect).
The related files are redirect.env and output.sh

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be working (at least not any more). You would usually get `script.sh: line 5: exec: 1: not found`

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to display logs on stdout and log file along with the timestamp. None of the above answers worked for me. 
I made use of **process substitution** and **exec** command and came up with the following code.
Sample logs:

```
2017-06-21 11:16:41+05:30 Fetching information about files in the directory...
```

Add following lines at the top of your script:

```
LOG_FILE=script.log
exec > >(while read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)" "$line" | tee -a $LOG_FILE; done)
exec 2> >(while read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)" "$line" | tee -a $LOG_FILE; done >&2)
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Is it possible to log all application errors to log into host directory so that it will helps devops....

Answer (score 5):

for log file you may date to enter into text data. following code may help

```
# declaring variables

Logfile="logfile.txt"   
MAIL_LOG="Message to print in log file"  
Location="were is u want to store log file"

cd $Location   
if [ -f $Logfile ]  
then   
echo "$MAIL_LOG " >> $Logfile

else        

touch $Logfile   
echo "$MAIL_LOG" >> $Logfile    

fi
```

ouput: 2.   Log file will be created in first run and keep on updating from next runs. In case log file missing in future run , script will create new log file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it will do the work:

```
log_file=$curr_dir/log_file.txt
exec > >(tee -a ${log_file} )
exec 2> >(tee -a ${log_file} >&2)
```

Comment: This `exec > >(tee -a ${log_file} )` works perfect for my needs. Previous solutions above would interrupt parts of my script that force exit if they failed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to get the desired output. Though it may be somewhat unorthodox way. Anyways here it goes. In the redir.env file I have following code:

```
#####redir.env#####    
export LOG_FILE=log.txt

      exec 2>>${LOG_FILE}

    function log {
     echo "$1">>${LOG_FILE}
    }

    function message {
     echo "$1"
     echo "$1">>${LOG_FILE}
    }
```

Then in the actual script I have the following codes:

```
#!/bin/sh 
. redir.env
echo "Echoed to console only"
log "Written to log file only"
message "To console and log"
echo "This is stderr. Written to log file only" 1>&2
```

Here **echo** outputs only to console, **log** outputs to only log file  and **message** outputs to both the log file and console.

After executing the above script file I have following outputs:

In console

> ***In console***
>   Echoed to console only
>   To console and log

For the Log file

> ***In Log File***
>   Written to log file only
>   This is stderr. Written to log file only
>   To console and log

Hope this help.

Comment: I appreciated this solution.  It's simple and straightforward compared to some of the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
    #
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # echo pass params and print them to a log file and terminal
    # with timestamp and $host_name and $0 PID
    # usage:
    # doLog "INFO some info message"
    # doLog "DEBUG some debug message"
    # doLog "WARN some warning message"
    # doLog "ERROR some really ERROR message"
    # doLog "FATAL some really fatal message"
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    doLog(){
        type_of_msg=$(echo $*|cut -d" " -f1)
        msg=$(echo "$*"|cut -d" " -f2-)
        [[ $type_of_msg == DEBUG ]] && [[ $do_print_debug_msgs -ne 1 ]] && return
        [[ $type_of_msg == INFO ]] && type_of_msg="INFO " # one space for aligning
        [[ $type_of_msg == WARN ]] && type_of_msg="WARN " # as well

        # print to the terminal if we have one
        test -t 1 && echo " [$type_of_msg] `date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S %Z"` [$run_unit][@$host_name] [$$] ""$msg"

        # define default log file none specified in cnf file
        test -z $log_file && \
            mkdir -p $product_instance_dir/dat/log/bash && \
                log_file="$product_instance_dir/dat/log/bash/$run_unit.`date "+%Y%m"`.log"
        echo " [$type_of_msg] `date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S %Z"` [$run_unit][@$host_name] [$$] ""$msg" >> $log_file
    }
    #eof func doLog
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it very useful to append both stdout and stderr to a log file. I was glad to see a solution by alfonx with `exec > >(tee -a)`, because I was wondering how to accomplish this using `exec`. I came across a creative solution using here-doc syntax and `.`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80707/how-to-output-text-to-both-screen-and-file-inside-a-shell-script

I discovered that in zsh, the here-doc solution can be modified using the "multios" construct to copy output to both stdout/stderr and the log file:

```
#!/bin/zsh
LOG=$0.log
# 8 is an arbitrary number;
# multiple redirects for the same file descriptor 
# triggers "multios"
. 8<<\EOF /dev/fd/8 2>&2 >&1 2>>$LOG >>$LOG
# some commands
date >&2
set -x
echo hi
echo bye
EOF
echo not logged
```

It is not as readable as the `exec` solution but it has the advantage of allowing you to log just part of the script. Of course, if you omit the EOF then the whole script is executed with logging. I'm not sure how `zsh` implements multios, but it may have less overhead than `tee`. Unfortunately it seems that one cannot use multios with `exec`.